# Jquery sliding three divs on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I want the header and footer to remain in their positions but the three (inline-block elements) in the center to slide in from the right side when page loads. You can see what I am trying to achieve on this example page: 
http://flooring-by-design.com

Here is my website where I want to achieve this same effect:http://contestlancer.com/davidicus/

As you can see it is twitter boot strap site. So the three divs which I want to slide in are inline-block elements with class="span4" and unique id.  I tried this but it doesn't work on the page for some reason.

```
   $("#portfolio").animate({left: "0"}, {
    duration: 2000       
    });

    $("#music").animate({left: "0"}, {
    duration: 1000
    });

    $("#blog").animate({left: "0"}, {
    duration: 500        
    });
```

Regards
Ahmar

Comment: I see that `left` is set to 0px for all three divisions. Can you update it to 110% and see. Also in the script that I can see in your page the IDs are still showing as #one, #two, #three. Please update this as mentioned in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
     $('#portfolio').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#portfolio').animate({
                    'right' : '100px'
                }, 2000);                    
            });
```

Comment: No It doesn't work at all. I am looking to animate on page load but this doesn't work with click either.